# about vb.net using mysql connection

Tags: mysql, dataset, timeout, vb.net-2010

my code is in vb.net.in back end am using mysql. mysql table contain data upto 25crores. 
i want to move the data from table into data set. table contain column as phone numbers in varchar datatype.move that entire data into dataset.

error

---

**am getting error like connection time out expired.then i add the following line in my code**

```
code
-----
 mycommand1 = New MySqlCommand("select fld_phonenumber from tbl_dndno ", myconnection1)
        ada = New MySqlDataAdapter(mycommand1)
        ada.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0 ' the code to increase the command timeout for dataadapter.

        ada.Fill(ds1)
        myconnection1.Close()
```

now am not able to see the values in dataset. the code keep on running. didn't show any result or error.please help me to this? I am new to vb.net

Comment: what happen if you remove this line? `ada.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0` ?

Comment: @John Totet Woo getting error like connection timeout

Comment: Can you check the ds1.Tables.Count property to make sure the dataset has data? If it does, can you check the ds1.Tables(0).Rows.Count property to make sure there are rows being returned? If not, maybe there are no rows in the table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move less data and let the user PAGE it (like page 1, page 2, page 3, etc) and only load maybe 100,000 or 200,00 or 300,000 or 400,000 or even 500,000 records on each load sequence?

after all even if you show 1000 records per page that still makes screen 100 pages each time you load it!

If its taking that long to load 20+ crore records.... It will take EVEN longer to RENDER the data to a page!!!

Also the option is there to load based upon FIRST ALPHABETIC letter....
After all if someone wants to find contact/person/id of SMITH then whats the point of loading JONES, BAKER, PATEL, KHAN??